# jQuery Validation Plugin stopping form submission, submit button won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script using jQuery validation plugin - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation - is preventing the form from sending that is found here:

http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/book2.php

Please fill in the form and watch the validation messages disappear then try to press send, this seems not to send and I don't understand why.

When this script is removed the contact form will function correctly and allow sending. Therefore I think it is causing the problem. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});;
</script>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#aform").validate({
              rules: {
                  postcode: {required: true,minlength: 6},
               phone: {required: true,number: true}

              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running the validator in debug mode. The [relevant documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) says (emphasis mine):

> **debug** Boolean Default: `false`
>
> Enables debug mode. If `true`, *the form is not submitted* and certain errors are displayed on the console
>   (requires Firebug or Firebug lite). Try to enable when a form is just
>   submitted instead of validation stopping the submit.

Removing the `debug: true` option will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time Frédéric, this has solved the problem.